# IF doesn't work inside each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

**any** if statement I put inside this function refuses to work.
The statement is true for some elements with this class and false for some, however **all** ignore it
(This is very stripped functionality just to locate the problem...)

```
$(".bought").each(function(index) {
Height = $(this).css("height")
    if (Height > 19) {
        alert(Height);
    }
});
```

this does work:

```
$(".bought").each(function(index) {
Height = $(this).css("height")
    alert(Height);
});
```

Comment: Try debugging to see `Height` value and if you ever get to the `if` statement.

Comment: There appears to be a missing `;` on line two in the first block, is this the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).css("height")` returns string...you need to parse this in int before applying comparison..

```
 Height = parseInt($(this).css("height"),10)
if (Height > 19) {         alert(Height);     }
```

Comment: `parseInt($(this).css("height"), 10)`

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".bought").each(function(index) {
    thisHeight = $(this).height()
    if (thisHeight > 19) {
        alert(thisHeight);
    }
});
```

That works!
http://jsfiddle.net/NmHb3/

Answer (score 1):

`Height` is returned as a string. The comparision is actually `"19" > 19` which yields `false`.

Try converting it to an integer:

```
if (parseInt(Height) > 19) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: But `"20" > 19` yields true. The string is converted to a number. And never forget to pass the radix to `parseInt`!

Answer (score 0):

The below code which you have used returns 'px' appended to the result so you can't compare it to '19'

```
Height = $(this).css("height")
```

Parse it like this and let us know how you get on :)

```
parseInt($(this).css('height'), 10);
```